# Branch link does not open activity with custom permission in android

Tags: android, branch.io

I am using using branch links to open my app from messages. But to avoid anybody opening my activity maliciously, I have created a custom permission and applied that to my activity. Now when the branch link tries to open the activity, it crashes. How can I fix this issue. Branch link works fine without custom permission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share stack trace.

Comment: How will it help?

Answer (score 2):

According to the comment on [Android: Is it a good practice to define custom permission for an activity which has intent filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334915/android-is-it-a-good-practice-to-define-custom-permission-for-an-activity-which/44335038?noredirect=1#comment75678041_44335038), one should not define custom permission for the activity itself.